# integer argument in python's argparse throws error "invalid int value" expecting a path

Tags: python, argparse

I'm tryting to use one integer as positional argument in argparse. Given is the following complete python script (taken from [this](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) tutorial):

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   import argparse
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument("square", help="display a square of a given number",
                    type=int)
   args = parser.parse_args()
   print args.square**2
```

When I call this script as

```
   > script.py 3
```

I get as a result

```
   error: argument square: invalid int value: 'C:\\home\\dev\\freqana\\3'
```

`argparse` clearly expects a filesystem path here, but why? The `type` is for sure set to `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct. I ran your program on python 2.7 and got the expected answer:

```
> script.py 3
9
```

Are you running the right code? cat (linux) or type (windows) script.py to make sure you have the latest, and then run under python explicitly to make sure you aren't picking up a different script.py on your path (python script.py 3)

Comment: Thanks for this. My fault: The system did indeed picked up something different. With your assurance that the code is right, it was easy for me to find the culprit.